# R: with resecpt to two variables in a dataset, third variable in another dataset to be identified

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe (lets called it as df_A) with variables Material Code, Usage%, Month-Year.
Have another dataframe(df_B) with variables Material Code, Material Description, Month-Year.

Need to get the Usage % from df_A, based on Month-Year of df_A and its corresponding Material Code in df_B and paste the Usage% as another column in df_B
InFO: The count of the Material Code in df_A and df_B might not be the same. Hence based on the mon-yr in df_B, then its corresponding Material code in df_B; then each matching Material Code of df_A and its corresponding Mon-Yr in df_A, the usage has to be got.
Image attached for data visualization

[image]

Comment: Simply `merge` the two dfs on *Mon-Yr* and *Material Code*.

Comment: No, the two dataframes are different dimensions. One table with same material code might have 12 months, while the same material in other dataframe might have only 8 months.

Comment: For `merge` that does not matter. You can specify to keep all records in first df or second df (filling NAs for unmatched items) or both (i.e., `LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN`, or `OUTER JOIN`).

Comment: Also the number of columns variables are more than 20 for both the data frames. As well, the variables are not same for both dataframes. Just for easy understanding I have mentioned between 3 to 4 columns/variables here. Hence I'm not sure whether Merge can be used when I need only one column data(usage% from df_A) to df_B; for matching values ("df_A$Material_Code, df_A$Mon_Yr" and "df_B$Material_Code, df_B$Mon_Yr"). Pls suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, simply run a left join `merge` keeping all rows of *df_B* (i.e., `all.x=TRUE`) to map over the one needed column from *df_A*. And since you have many columns, select only the needed columns during the `merge`:

```
final_df <- merge(dfB[c("Material_Code", "Mon_Yr", "Material_Description")], 
                  dfA[c("Material_Code", "Mon_Yr", "Used %")],
                  by=c("Material_Code", "Mon_Yr"), all.x=TRUE)

# RE-ORDER COLUMNS
final_df <- final_df[c("Material_Code", "Material_Description", "Used %", "Mon_Yr")]
```